# How to refresh div with jquery, without duplicating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to refresh a div every 10 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
        $('#feed').load('forum.php #feed').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
</script>
```

Works great, except the first load (after 10 seconds) makes a duplicate of this div, so it's one sitting atop the other. After that, the div refreshes properly every 10 seconds, without making any more duplicates.

Any ideas what's wrong with my code? The div is:

```
<div id="feed">... stuff ... </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like a race condition. Try `$('#feed').load('forum.php').fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a duplicate with the code you have provided.

Comment: @BumbleB2na, thank you for your response - that code makes the entire page blank upon loading

Comment: @KevinB I wonder if it has something to do with the forum software I'm using. Basically just trying to use jquery to refresh the sidebar/post feed. Maybe it reloads itself at some point?

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of container. **This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the element with an ID of result**, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.

So you are inserting the same element into the page multiple times.

Try changing your selector to

```
$('#feed').load('forum.php #feed>*').fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - this still results in the first duplicated div. I think this must have something to do with the forum software.

Comment: what is the deal about `>*` ? i use the load function without this part. And everything looks fine. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with vBulletin's sidebar code - I broadened the refresh div to encompass the entire sidebar, instead of just the "Recent Posts" block. Just wanted to post here on the unlikely chance that anyone has the exact same issue.

Thank you everyone for your help!